# How to write multiple arguments with single variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm using a single structure dynamically for many function as shown below:

```
Parent[funcName](data, function(err) {
   // further operations
});
```

The variable "data" in the function have 0, 1, 2 or 3 as per the function requirement. It works fine when single argument is passed in "data" but if more than 1, it shows error - "more argument are expected".

So how can I pass multiple arguments by using single variable? Is there any work around?

Comment: Pass an object.

Comment: pass data as an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use the spread operator

```
Parent[funcName](...data, function(err) {
   // further operations
});
```

where `data` is the array of all the parameters you have passed.

Comment: You could use the above syntax (rest parameters) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters but is not supported in Edge or IE

Answer (score 1):

Just make use of the `arguments` object:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

or this way:

```
function foo(...args) {
  return args;
}
foo(1, 2, 3); // [1,2,3]
```

greetings